# Cypress, how to check for text typed into a field?

Tags: cypress

I can verify text appears "somewhere" on the results page with

```javascript
it.only('can verify an input element has certain text typed into it', function() {
  cy.visit('http://google.com')
  cy.get("input[name=q]").type('abc123{enter}')  // with or without the {enter}
  cy.contains('abc123') // Anywhere on the page :(
})
```

but how can I verify the text I type **in the input text box**?

I tried chaining to the element with

```javascript
it.only('can verify an input element has certain text typed into it', function() {
  cy.visit('http://google.com')
  cy.get("input[name=q]").type('abc123{enter}')
  cy.get("input[name=q]").contains('abc123')
})
```

but I get

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'abc123' within the element: <input.gLFyf.gsfi> but never did.
```

I tried `cy.get("input[name=q]").contains('abc123')` and
`cy.contains('input[name=q]', 'abc123')`
but both time out and fail.

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60348107 ? I'm curious

Comment: see answer below

Comment: I was referring to your question I linked to above, about `^` and `$` anchors in Vim, which was deleted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Change `.contains` to use `.should('have.value'...`**

```
cy.get("input[name=q]").type('abc123{enter}')
cy.get("input[name=q]").should('have.value', 'abc123')
```

Comment: May be we can write that test in one line and assert that `cy.get("input[name=q]").type('abc123{enter}').should('have.value', 'abc123')`

Comment: @soccerway Depends, since he is typing `{enter}` at the end, he might be posting the form which can trigger a page reload. Not sure Cypress would have time to make the assertion if it happened. But otherwise yes, as shown here by Cypress: https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions

Answer (score 0):

You may not like this idea but here is just a suggestion so you don't have to keep calling `cy.get` each time.

You could always set a const value for your input name (could be in an external file) so:

```
export const inputField = () => cy.get('input[name=q]');
```

This will do the get whenever you call inputField.

so then your call would be:

```
inputField.type('abc123{enter}').should('have.value', 'abc123');
```

Thats just more a setup thing than an actual soluton, as I know you solved the issue yourself, but the above is quite a nice way so you don't have to keep doing cy.get on the same field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using contains, you can read the text you already entered in the input field using "then()". Here's how:

`cy.get("input[name=q]").type('abc123').then(function($input){ const value = $input.text() expect(value.includes('abc123')).to.be.true })`